# How does parentNode.removeChild() actually works?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, removechild

I'm building a 'Snake' game, so I've built a 'board' using a two dimensional array.

When the snake moves, I'm adding an `img` element to the top and removing an `img` element from the end.

When I'm 'removing' the element by simply changing the `src` attribute to ' ', it works but it seems like bad practice.

When I'm trying to actually remove the element, it does not work and it actually seems to be 'blocking' the 'drawNewHead' function. Right after the first remove occurs, the snake stops moving.

Here's the code:

```
let snakeLength = 3;
const body = document.querySelector('body');

function drawNewHead(left, top)
{
    const newLink = document.createElement('img');

    newLink.src = "Images/CirceledLink.png";
    newLink.style.top = `${top}px`;
    newLink.style.left = `${left}px`;
    newLink.id = `${left}, ${top}`;

    body.appendChild(newLink);
}

function removeLastLink(currHeadLeft)
{
    let lastLinkLeft = currHeadLeft - (snakeLength * 100);
    let id = `${lastLinkLeft}, 100`;
    const linkToRemove = document.getElementById(id);

    body.removeChild(linkToRemove);
}
```

Am I using the removeChild function wrong? I also tried `linkToRemove.remove();` and `linkToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(linkToRemove)`

Comment: "id" attribute values cannot contain spaces.

Comment: @Pointy I'm pretty sure that's not true, it's just annoying to use the ID as a CSS selector if it has spaces

Comment: @Pointy Hey, thank you for responding, tried to remove the spacing but it doesn't change anything

Comment: To be clear: `${left}, ${top}` should be `${left},${top}`. Also, no two elements can have the same "id" value. Oh, also, in `removeLastLink()` that space also has to go.

Comment: @Pointy, yup, removed from ``removeLastLink()``` as well and made sure there are no two identical values.

Comment: @Sheraff nope, no whitespace allowed. https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Coder well use the browser debugger to verify that you can fetch the elements by the id values, and add debugging to `removeLastLink()` to verify that `getElementById()` is returning non-null.

Comment: @Pointy IDs with spaces work for me, at least in Chrome's `getElementById()`. I'm not saying it's a good idea though

Comment: @Phil I'm not surprised, but the spec is pretty explicit.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for correcting me with a link to the specs